# Can we call population CDF a statistical parameter (particularly, an estimand)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let's look at the definition of the word "parameter" in statistics

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter) wikipedia says that

> A statistical parameter (or population parameter) is a quantity that can be regarded as a numerical characteristic of a population or a statistical model.
>
> Even if a family of distributions is not specified, quantities such as the mean and variance can still be regarded as parameters of the distribution of the population from which a sample is drawn.

And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter#Statistics_and_econometrics) it says

> It is possible to make statistical inferences without assuming a particular parametric family of probability distributions. In that case, one speaks of non-parametric statistics as opposed to the parametric statistics.

---

So we can consider quantities such as population mean, population variance as parameters because they are charasteristics of population. Therefore we can also consider them as unknown estimands (*an estimand is that which is to be estimated in a statistical analysis i.e. the parameter which we want to find*).

But what about the population CDF (or PDF in case of continuous distributions)? (It's not a number, it's a function!)
**Can we call popualtion CDF a statistical parameter in any statistical problem? Can we call population CDF an estimand and solve problem that sounds like "Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. sample from a population with CDF $F$. You need to estimate $F$"?**

*As I guess the above mentioned problem is from non-parametric statistic, right?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call the population mean or the population variance "parameters" when there is no parametrized family of distributions. Certainly estimating the c.d.f. based on the data is done, but I would not call it a parameter.